# MailChimp integration

Tags: mailchimp

Now that SL MailChimp Subscribe is no longer in development*, is there an alternative that I can use to sign-up members to a MailChimp list?

*The extension throws a Javascript error for EE2.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick. There are a number of options.

https://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=mailchimp&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2

If you're getting a Javascript error with SL Mailchimp Subscriber then it's probably that it would be simple to fix. If you can provide some more details I'm sure someone could help you out.

But if you want something different then I've recently used Subscriber. Worked perfectly and easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Postmaster](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster)? It allows you to subscribe people to MailChimp and other platforms plus do additional things based on triggers. Not the cheapest, but definitely worth the money and easy to use.